# Is there a way to know the type of the dataextension programatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I could not find a field to determine the type of DataExtension (Standard, Filtered, Synchronized) using ssjs, AMPScript, REST or SOAP Api.
Has anynone faced this problem?

Comment: I don't believe there is, what use case are you trying to solve?

Comment: We are trying to retrieve all sendable + filtered dataExtensions which filter has been refreshed more than X days ago

Answer (score 0):

The `DataExtensionTemplate` property may be able to provide you that information.

> Indicates template used to create a data extension.

You can perform a retrieve on the [DataExtension object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm).

Comment: Filtered data extensions doesn't have template assigned, I tried with SOAP API and WSProxy which are basically the same.